# Can I avoid triggering a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In my app, every time an user deletes a comment that he/she made in a post, a cloud function is triggered to update some property inside user's record in the users collection. Like: ***on comment delete, update user's record.***

However, when deleting user's account and consequently its comments, that cloud function is triggered, since the comments are being deleted.

Because the account is being deleted, I don't need that update inside the user's collection to happen.

Is there a way of avoiding triggering a Google Cloud Function if a condition is met, like, "if deleting account, return null"?

Can I pass an argument to the function so I can use it as a condition?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't awoid triggering them but you can detect if the `comment` is deleted by the user or another cloud function that is "cleaning" user data from a user that gets deleted by checking the `auth` type like here:

```js
.onUpdate((eventSnapshot, context) => {
    if (context.authType === 'ADMIN') {
      // This cloud function is triggered by another cloud function so we exit here
      return null
    }
```

If you delete all user data when a user gets deleted by using a cloud function you can use this method to just exit the other cloud functions that would be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you're using [Cloud Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) and I assume (!?) you're using [`OnWrite`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#function_triggers) events.

`OnWrite` includes create, update **and** delete.

One solution is to create `OnCreate` and `OnUpdate` triggers instead.

If you don't permit your users to update comments, then you just need `OnCreate`.

Comment: I'm using onDelete in the Comments subcollection. When a comment is deleted, this function will update the user's record. What I need is to only cause this update if I'm not deleting the account.

Comment: With the mutual dependency between Users and Comments, you can't avoid the cascade of events. Not knowing much about your implementation, you may want to reconsider triggering an update on a User when a document in one of its collections is updated.