# How to avoid Firebase Cloud Functions invocations?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firestore collection called "documents":

```
db
 \documents
   \$documentId
```

I have created a cloud function that fires each time a new document is added/deleted. This function increments/decrements a number in the real-time database at:

```
db
 \documents
   \$documentId: 10,000
```

My boss asked me to implement a delete account option that can delete all user documents.

What I have tried is to create another cloud function that fires when the user deletes the account in authentication. The problem arises when I delete all the documents in the collection, because for each document delete, the first function fires and decrements the number in the real-time database and I don't want the function to be invoked. How to avoid the first cloud function to decrement the number in real-time database, when I delete all documents in Firestore using cloud function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to dynamically control whether the Cloud Function fires or not.

The options I can think of:

- Filter based on some value in the documents, such as FaBotch says in their answer - and as Doug answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59314716/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-firebase-functions-firestore-triggers)
- Before starting the delete, write some other flag value somewhere to indicate that you don't want to further process this user's data, and then read that in the Cloud Function.
- Let the Cloud Function finish its decrement counts, and then at some point post-process the counter.

While that last one may sound hacky, it's actually what I often end up doing: removing spurious counters once a day or so.

For completeness: *the Firebase CLI has a `database:import` command that takes a `--disable-triggers` flag that is somewhat what you want, but that only exists on the CLI (not the API),  it doesn't work for deletes, and does not exist for Firestore.*

Also see:

- [Can I avoid triggering a Google Cloud Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69258690/can-i-avoid-triggering-a-google-cloud-function)
- [Is there a way to suppress Firebase Functions Firestore triggers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59314716/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-firebase-functions-firestore-triggers)

Answer (score 0):

Do you save the user id in the documents collection? if yes, when onDelete is called you can check if `userId != "userId_deleted"` and then call the code to decrement or not